# Differences between Windows Server 2008 and Windows MultiPoint Server 2011

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-multipoint-server

I'm wondering about the differences between Windows MultiPoint Server 2011 and Windows Server 2008 R2 but only from a MultiPoint Server 2011 perspective. For example, I don't care what Multipoint Server 2011 has that Windows Server 2008 R2 doesn't, I only care about what windows Server 2008 R2 has that MultiPoint doesn't. Is there a product feature matrix available?

Answer (score 1):

think this explans it all
http://www.youtube.com/user/msmultipoint#p/u/0/eT2zE5tMglM

Comment: thanks , but actually this doesn't answer the question,"I don't care what Multi-Point Server 2011 has that Windows Server 2008 R2 doesn't". that video shows exactly what i don't care about...

Comment: Well in my world MP server and server R2 are two different products, R2 is a server OS where MP is some screen sharing thingy.

this doc. have some of MP keyfeatures

http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/14114_na/14114_na.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the link.. However Windows MP Server 2011 is based on the core Windows Server 2008 R2 actually its windows Server 2008 R2 with Extensions, i hope someone with experience in MP 2011 server would show up and let us know if they did restrict any R2 Features in MP server 2011.

Answer (score 0):

There is a features matrix on Page 38 of the [Deployment Guide](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8290).

That's about as specific as any of the MS literature on the subject gets, I think. Note that most of the features available in 2008 R2 Std appear to be available under Roles 7 Features, but a good chunk of them are untested or might be generally broken, especially running as a Domain Controller.

As for 2008 R2 Std itself, see here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/windows-server/2008-r2-features.aspx